# Is it possible to use Typescript and ES6 in extension development in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

When I set `target` to `es6`, everything seems to be alright - up until the point where I use a feature that requires a `--harmony` flag, like default parameters.

It seems like the way to fix this would be to pass e.g. `--harmony-default-parameters` into the node process... but I don't even think there is a node process. I attempted to pass `--js-flags="--harmony-default-parameters"` into the electron process, by putting the following in my launch.json:

```
"runtimeArgs": ["--js-flags=\"--harmony --harmony-default-parameters\""],
```

...but that didn't work, either.

Is this even possible?